# Setting the height of my section equal to text content, ignoring height of SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, grid

I am styling a section that contains textual elements (a heading, a paragraph, and a summary/details element containing a `ul` which in turn contains several `li` elements) and an SVG. I am using CSS grid to structure this content into two columns: one column for all the textual elements, and one column (pushed to the right extreme of the screen using `justify-self: end`) for my SVG.

As you can see in the code snippet below, regardless of whether or not my summary/details element is closed or expanded, the height of my section is always equal to the height of my SVG.

I would like for the height of my section to always be equal to the height of my text content, even when the summary/details element is closed (in which case, the height of the section would be much shorter than it is currently, and the remainder of the SVG would be cut off -- it is important that it is cut off, but not squeezed).

Is this possible? Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

**(The output of the code snippet below might make a bit more sense if you open it as a full page.)**

```js
var clickDetails = document.getElementById("click-details");

function showDetails() {
    if (clickDetails.innerHTML === "Click here to show full syllabus") {
        clickDetails.innerHTML = "Click here to hide..."
    } else {
        clickDetails.innerHTML = "Click here to show full syllabus"
    }
}
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.span-row-1 {
    grid-row: span 1 / auto;
    justify-self: end;
}

object {
    /* height:  */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="grid">
                <div>
                    <h4>Title</h4>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem, architecto unde iure deserunt veniam hic reprehenderit perspiciatis in itaque labore facilis nemo reiciendis nulla a voluptatem voluptates quos sint? Tempore.</p>
                    <h5 class="syllabus-text">Syllabus</h5>
                    <details>
                        <summary id="click-details" onclick="showDetails()" class="syllabus-text">Click here to show full syllabus</summary>
                        <ul class="syllabus browser-default">
                            <li class="header-section"><a href="#Introduction">Introduction</a>
                                <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                    <li>Stuff goes here</li>
                        </ul>
                    </details>
                </div>
                <div class="span-row-1">
                       <svg width="590" height="900" viewBox="0 0 590 900" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M570 -580C589.882 -580 606 -563.882 606 -544L606 959C606 978.882 589.882 995 570 995H182.054C149.285 995 125.984 947.458 136.202 916.323C155.065 858.84 158.723 770.828 90 655.5C-40.5 436.5 291.5 781.5 90 253.5C-84.2112 -202.994 42.8138 -493.173 80.4145 -563.397C86.1259 -574.064 97.2813 -580 109.381 -580H570Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="606" y1="-675.5" x2="429.743" y2="1137.1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#DE7575"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#7090CE"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>

                </div>
              
              </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h5>Beginning of next section</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum aliquid qui repellendus! Provident, laborum quaerat vel, officiis quidem amet sequi aut repellendus architecto itaque expedita saepe perferendis ullam distinctio iure.
                Repudiandae error est in perferendis quo ex illo at itaque ad ullam amet nostrum sed, inventore animi ipsa cupiditate vel tenetur eius dolorem explicabo asperiores facilis blanditiis voluptatem? Temporibus, aperiam!
                Dicta voluptatum libero quis soluta consequuntur aliquam iste quo officia voluptates nihil suscipit ullam, maiores quam deleniti perspiciatis minus obcaecati tenetur. Officia provident natus quod aut laborum quidem perspiciatis ad!</p>
            </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try add this code to your css file to style the svg

```
svg {
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

You could also try using your svg as a background image. 
Inside "span-row-1" add:

```
<img class="bg-image" src="your-img-url.svg">
```

and then apply this CSS style

```
.bg-image {
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the reply, but I'm not seeing any difference on my end.